# VBA program to color all cells that have a value

Tags: excel, vba

I just started teaching myself VBA so thanks in advance. Why is this giving me an error? The code searches for the column of dates that are in the future. Then searches in that column for any cells that have a value and colors them yellow.

Thanks!

```
    Sub Macro1()
     Dim cell As Range
     Dim cell2 As Range
     Dim ColumnN As Long



For Each cell In Range("I2:ZZ2")

    If cell.Value > Now() Then

    '

    ColumnN = cell.Column
    ColumnL = ConvertToLetter(ColumnN)
    MsgBox ColumnL & cell.Row

        For Each cell2 In Range("ColumnL:ColumnL")

            If Not cell2 Is Empty Then



                cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            End If

        Next cell2
    End If
   End Sub()





    Function ConvertToLetter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    ConvertToLetter = vArr(0)
    End Function
```

Comment: What error is it giving? Might consider editing your post and including the details of that.

Comment: 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed which points to  "For Each cell2 in Range("ColumnL:ColumnL")

Comment: What's the purpose of looking in range ColumnL? I see you want to look from column I to ZZ, but that line (the columnL selection) will only look in whatever column that is.

Comment: does conditional formatting not work for this?

Comment: Conditional formatting would work if I was trying to just highlight the future dates. I want to highlight the values under the columns of the specific date... I think it still might work in formatting somehow but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @acushner        tag above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there!
There's two main problems to fix:

replace:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("ColumnL:ColumnL")
```

with

```
For Each cell2 In Range(ColumnL & ":" & ColumnL)
```

and

```
If Not cell2 Is Empty Then
```

with

```
If Not IsEmpty(cell2) Then
```

This should result in the following:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim ColumnN As Long
Dim ColumnL As String


For Each cell In Range("I2:ZZ2")

    If cell.Value > Now() Then

        ColumnN = cell.Column
        ColumnL = ConvertToLetter(ColumnN)
        MsgBox ColumnL & cell.Row

        For Each cell2 In Range(ColumnL & ":" & ColumnL)

            If Not IsEmpty(cell2) Then



                cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            End If

        Next cell2

    End If
Next cell

End Sub


    Function ConvertToLetter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    ConvertToLetter = vArr(0)
    End Function
```

Although it is a little inefficient it gets the job done!

Comment: does take a long time haha, ill work on that. thanks!

Comment: @heyjaynell - after your `Dim` statements, add this `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then, right before `End Sub` add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.  This will turn off screen refreshing, so the screen won't change (you won't see any highlights) until the macro finishes.  This can help to speed up macros.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks so much for your help!  that seemed to help some.. Wondering if it might be my computer as well I tried shortening the ranges because they aren't that important or strict

Comment: I see you keep jumping back and forth as to which code is the answer, haha - do they both get *close* to what you want? Or do you like one over the other? (Just curious, not for the "points", but just to see if I understood, etc.).

Comment: @BruceWayne honestly I've never used this site before I thought I could accept them both... haha... The above answer achieves the end result I wanted with minimal changing from my original code, but yours works as well.. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @heyjaynell, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a cell is empty, you need to switch the order of how that's done.  Switch your `If Not` statement to `If Not IsEmpty(cell2) Then`.

Also, it is highly recommended not to name your variables `cell`, because this is a close to some "special words" (I forget the technical term) Excel uses.  I always just use `cel` instead.

```
Sub test()
Dim cel     As Range
Dim cel2    As Range
Dim ColumnN As Long

For Each cel In Range("I2:ZZ2")

    If cel.Value > Now() Then

        ColumnN = cel.Column
        ' ColumnL = ConvertToLetter(ColumnN)
        ' MsgBox ColumnL & cell.Row
        If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Edit: If you notice, I also tweaked your `cell2` `range`.  This removed the need to run another macro (which can be a cause of issues sometimes), so you only need the column Number.

Edit2: I removed the "ColumnL" range selection - what is that for? I can add it back in,  but wasn't sure why you'd loop through I:ZZ columns, but only have the highlighting in column N.

Edit2:

I tweaked the code, now it's much shorter and should run a bit faster:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim lastCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastCol = Cells(2, 9).End(xlToRight).Column ' Note, this assumes there are NO gaps in the columns from I:ZZ
'lastCol = cells(2,16384).End(xltoleft).column ' use this instead, if there are gaps in I2:ZZ2

Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(2, lastCol))

For Each cel In rng

    If cel.Value > Now() Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to change the entire column to yellow though including the empty cells.

Comment: Updated - although, I removed a part (see my OP).  What this does is look through each cell in row 2, from column `I` to `ZZ` and if a date that is beyond today, it highlights yellow.